# Undefined index with submit button in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is the first page: Index.php

```html
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Index</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="Index" action="Result.php" method="POST">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="off"><br><br> 1. I identify my gender as... <br> &ensp;&ensp;
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male<br> &ensp;&ensp;
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female<br> &ensp;&ensp;
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="others">Others<br><br>
    <input type="submit" a href="Test2.php" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
<?php
session_destroy();
?>
```

The second page: Test2.php

```html
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test2</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="Result.php" method="POST">
    2. What is your age?<br> &ensp;&ensp;
    <input type="radio" name="age" value="14years">Under 14 years old<br> &ensp;&ensp;
    <input type="radio" name="age" value="15years">15-24 years old<br> &ensp;&ensp;
    <input type="radio" name="age" value="25years">25-59 years old<br> &ensp;&ensp;
    <input type="radio" name="age" value="60years">60-74 years old<br> &ensp;&ensp;
    <input type="radio" name="age" value="75years">Above 75 years old<br><br><br><br>
    <input type="submit" a href="Test3.php" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
<?php
session_destroy();
?>
```

Third page: Test3.php

```html
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test3</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="Result.php" method="POST">
    3. Please specify your ethnicity (race)<br> &ensp;&ensp;
    <input type="radio" name="race" value="chinese">Chinese<br> &ensp;&ensp;
    <input type="radio" name="race" value="malay">Malay<br> &ensp;&ensp;
    <input type="radio" name="race" value="indian">Indian<br> &ensp;&ensp;
    <input type="radio" name="race" value="others">Others<br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
<?php
session_destroy();
?>
```

This is the last page which is receiving the three php files' values: Result.php:

```html
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Result</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <?php
if (isset($_POST))
{
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 echo 'Welcome! ' .$username. '<br>';
}
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
if ($gender == "others")
    echo "<font size='5'>You are not normal</font><br><br>";
else
 echo "<font size='5'>You are normal</font><br><br>";

$age = $_POST['age'];
if (($age == "60years") || ($age == "75years"))
    echo "<font size='5'>You are old man</font><br><br>";
else
 echo "<font size='5'>You are young man</font><br><br>";

$race = $_POST['race'];
if ($race == "others")
    echo "<font size='5'>You are from other race</font><br><br>";
else
 echo "<font size='5'>You are from one of three races</font><br><br>";
?>
</body>

</html>
<?php
session_destroy();
?>
```

The outcome is the undefined index on the Result.php. I search in the Internet and try different solutions. After that I think that my  button in each form has some problem but I failed to find some solution. So some explanations with codes will be a big help for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="Report.php" method="GET">
  Name: <input type=text name=username size=20><br><br>
</form>

// script
function GetParam(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

console.log(GetParam('username')); // will get the username query in the url
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `GetParam(username)` is accepting argument but while invoking `GetParam();` you don't have parameter. Remove `username` form `GetParam(username)` you don't to pass the username since you are getting it from query string.

```
function GetParam() {
    var start = location.search.indexOf("?" + username + "=");
    if (start < 0) start = location.search.indexOf("&" + username + "=");
    if (start < 0) return '';
    start += username.length + 2;
    var end = location.search.indexOf("&", start) - 1;
    if (end < 0) end = location.search.length;
    var result = '';
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        var c = location.search.charAt(i);
        result = result + (c == '+' ? ' ' : c);
    }
    return unescape(result);
}
result = GetParam();
username = unescape(result["username"]);
document.write("Hi " + username + "<br>");
```

With PHP you can get the parameter with `$_GET[]`

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["username"])){
 print("Hi ".$_GET["username"]);   
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a form as below in your html

```
<form method = "get" action="phpFileName.php">
    <input type="text" value="" name="name" placeholder="name"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

in your php file phpFileName.php script as below

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET["submit"])){
 print("Welcome ".$_GET["name"]);   
}
?>
```